# Should web api return generic data, or more specific logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Example, I have an mvc view that needs data from Student, Teacher & Class entities.  Should the web api have three different Gets, one more involved Get? So would it be:

(Note - the syntax may be a little of, these are just examples)

WebApi -

```
    public Student GetStudent(int StudentId)
    {
        // get student from db logic ;
    }

    public Teacher GetTeacherByStudent(int StudentId)
    {
        // get teacher from db logic ;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Class> GetClassesByStudent(int StudentId)
    {
        // get classes from db logic ;
    }
```

Then in the web front end, I would combine all that data into a viewmodel and send it to the view.

```
    public StudentDetailDTO GetStudentDetail(int studentId)
    {
        var data = _db.Student.Where(s => s.StudentId == studentId).Include(s => s.Teacher).Include(s => s.Class).ToList();

        StudentDetailViewModel vm = new StudentDetailViewModel()
        {
            // map data to a viewmodel
        }
        return View(vm);
    }
```

Or should I have the GetStudentDetial method in the web api and return all that data as one?

All the Gets will be in the Web Api regardless, because they are used in different instances.

Sending the data individually would keep the api generic, so it is more usable for other apps I will build in the future and will use this data.  But the back and forth to the server is a lot more, instead just one shot to get everything.

Comment: Another option to consider is to have one method that accepts arguments of which entities to return. For example, boolean parameters for whether or not the student, teacher, or class should be returned. This way, you could have one http request that returns one or any combination of these sets.

Comment: Interesting.  And this would open the option for pulling all the data from the web api in one shot.